# Question on Taylor theorem (for $n+1$ differentiable function)

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

> Taylor's theorem says the following: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ $n+1$ times differentiable on $]a,b[$ and $x_0 \in ]a,b[$. Then, $\forall x \in ]a,b[ \ \exists y \in ]x_0,x[$ s.t

$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(y)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$

where $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(y)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$ is the rest.

Moreover, if $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, we have that

$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(y)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}=o(|x-x_0|^n)$.

So, now i have a question:

In one of my exercices I have a function $f \in C^3$ such that at $x_0$ the function has a minimum and $f''(x_0)=0$ (the goal is to show then that $f'''(x_0)=0$ or not, but It is not my question).

In corrections the function $f$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ is written as the following (we put $x=x_0+h$)

$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\frac{1}{6}f'''(x_0)h^3+o(h^3)$

What I don't understand, is how we get the previous equality. By Taylor's theorem, we can express $f$ as the following:

$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\frac{f'''(y)}{3!}(x-x_0)^{n+1} $

for some $y \in ]x_0,x[$.

I don't understand how to get the same equality as before. Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f \in C^{n}$ you get the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ plus a remainder of the form $o(h^n)$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), for example.

With the stronger assumption $f \in C^{n+1}$, you can improve this to get the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ plus the Lagrange form of the remainder (as you wrote), which is of order $O(h^{n+1})$.

(Notice “little oh” in the first case and “big oh” in the second case.)

Comment: I read that wikipedia topic but I would like to know how to obtain the correction's form knowing only the theorem that I stated in the beginning.

Comment: You don't, that's a different version of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Hm... alright thank you. That's weird because professor wrties this expression and I saw only the stated theorem in my courses.. Can't you obtain it rewriting the $\frac{f'''(y)}{3!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}=\frac{f'''(y)}{3!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}+\frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}-\frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$?

Comment: Then I suggest that you ask the professor in question. There's no way for us strangers on the Internet to know what he or she actually meant.